# Is there any PowerShell or CSOM script in order to publish InfoPath forms to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, infopath, csom

I need to automate my task of publishing InfoPath forms to SharePoint Online using Powershell script or CSOM code.

Comment: I am also working on this. How far did you reach? I found a code for SP2013, but couldn't make it work. I made some changes so it works on SPO (at least, no error messages), but the most I could get is an error message when creating a form. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82b15a/deploy-custom-list-forms-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: No luck. I don't think there is a way for SharePoint Online. Had to do It manually

Comment: Well, ShareGate can do this, as it can copy whole libraries, including templates. Sot, there must be a way. However, I created a ticket at MS for this, and they told me there isn't any supported method.